# When i include datepicker js & css files through php include doesn't work, but works on if i put all the code in single php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating a PHP form so I am including PHP header files to my index page. all the files are correctly loading except jquery date picker files are not loading and if put all the jquery CDN files to the index page it works correctly. But I can't add all the codes in the index page. so help me out

```
<?php
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI/6e6d051d47b598ebab05857545f242caf2b4b48c/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI/6e6d051d47b598ebab05857545f242caf2b4b48c/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
?>
```

```
<?php include 'inc/header.php';?>

<div class="ui calendar" id="example1">
<div class="ui input left icon">
<i class="calendar icon"></i>
<input type="text" placeholder="Date/Time">
</div>
</div>
```

//

```
    $('#example1').calendar();
$('#example2').calendar({
  type: 'date'
});
$('#example3').calendar({
  type: 'time'
});
$('#rangestart').calendar({
  type: 'date',
  endCalendar: $('#rangeend')
});
$('#rangeend').calendar({
  type: 'date',
  startCalendar: $('#rangestart')
});
$('#example4').calendar({
  startMode: 'year'
});
$('#example5').calendar();
$('#example6').calendar({
  ampm: false,
  type: 'time'
});
$('#example7').calendar({
  type: 'month'
});
$('#example8').calendar({
  type: 'year'
});
$('#example9').calendar();
$('#example10').calendar({
  on: 'hover'
});
var today = new Date();
$('#example11').calendar({
  minDate: new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 5),
  maxDate: new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + 5)
});
$('#example12').calendar({
  monthFirst: false
});
$('#example13').calendar({
  monthFirst: false,
  formatter: {
    date: function (date, settings) {
      if (!date) return '';
      var day = date.getDate();
      var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
      var year = date.getFullYear();
      return day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
    }
  }
});
$('#example14').calendar({
  inline: true
});
$('#example15').calendar();
```

I want to include datepicker js & css files through php file using  instead of putting all cdn files to index.php

Comment: Is custom.js file being included, check for the path. Look into console if the files are script files are being loaded.

Comment: In your first code block, you put `<?php   ?>` around HTML code.  Remove that.  The `<link>` and `<script>` tags are HTML, not PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI/6e6d051d47b598ebab05857545f242caf2b4b48c/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI/6e6d051d47b598ebab05857545f242caf2b4b48c/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Remove php tags and your scripts will be included accurately. You are using html tags inside php block.That's the reason they are not rendered.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Bipin Thakur. for your answer actually, I entered the wrong path for CDN files.
so after inspecting I got the error and corrected it.
Anyway, thank you for your immediate response.  project is working fine.

Comment: Glad to know that